# loss data when refresh page angular 8

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular8, behaviorsubject

**i am losing my role type when refresh the page i made something like if user Admin 
display dashboard button and user logged in i get the JWT token from server and put it in localstorage and inside the token userID and Role**

in my service i used BehaviorSubject as a string 
and i have function take the token and split it to take the part of body and take the role then Decode it

so if you can help me or something similar to my proplem(i saw like this proplem but all says put the value inside the LocalStorage and i already have put it

**AccountServicesService**

```
test$ :BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('') ;

Login(log: LoginModel): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.post<any>(this.HTTP_URL + 'ApplicationUser/Login' ,
   log, this.headers).pipe(map(x=> {
   this.test$.next(this.roleTypeForCheck(x.token));
   return x;
}));
}

roleTypeForCheck(token): string {
var payLoad = JSON.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1]));
var userRole = payLoad.role;
return userRole;
}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
login(){
if(this.loginForm.valid){
  this.validatLoginModel();
  this.service.Login(this.log).subscribe((res:any) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token',res.token);
    this.route.navigate(['home']);
  }, err => {
    if(err.status === 401){
      this.message = 'Email is not confirmed yet!!..Check Your Email';
    } else if(err.status === 400){
      this.message = 'username or password is incorrect';
    } else if(err.status === 500) {
      this.message = 'something wrong..try again later';
    }
    console.log(err);
  });
}
}
```

**NavBarComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log('init');
this.serv.test$.subscribe(res =>{
  this.userRole = res;
  console.log('subscr');
},err =>{
  alert(err.error);
});
```

**NavBarComponent.html**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="dashboard" *ngIf="(this.userRole) === 'Admin'">Dashboard</a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't want the user to login again after a page refresh. You already stored the token in the `localStorage` but after the refresh you have to read it from the same place. You could add a method, for example, in your `AccountServicesService`:

```
  getTokenFromLocalStorageWithoutLogin() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.test$.next(this.roleTypeForCheck(token));
  }
```

Comment: i have more thing when i am in login page and pres refresh page then i login as admin the dashboard <a> doesn't display...when i press refresh its Appear the logout and login many times it's still visible ...so the proplem in (the first login after rehresh) @Kari F.

Comment: Where did you put this line `const token = localStorage.getItem('token')`? Perhaps it doesn't get executed when you refresh the Login page. Put a `console.log(token)` after that line to see if it is executed.